# Make cgi-scripts "portable"

Tags: apache, perl, portability, cgi-bin

I've got a little project that uses perl cgi scripts. At this moment I use Apache to run these scripts. I have an index.html file that redirects to a cgi file.
Now I want to make my project 'portable', which means that I want to be able to move the project to another location without the need to configure apache (so not changing the cgi-bin directory in the configuration). The end product would be a script (or html file) that could be opened so that a browser would pop up, just like it would run as it would be using Apache. I actually don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you're asking. But I suspect you're about to find out why [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/) is such a good idea.

If you write your application to the PSGI interface then you'll be able to just drop it in to any PSGI-enabled web environment (or set up your own lightweight web server using something like [Starman](https://metacpan.org/pod/Starman)).